# Dynamic object not showing its methods

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I am trying to convert the ffg:,

**This Works**

```
IResultSEt rs =    db.SELECT.COLUMNS(db.GetTable(data.ToString()).ColumnNames).FROM(data.ToString()).Execute();
```

into this, which does not work,

```
dynamic rs = db.SELECT.COLUMNS(db.GetTable(data.ToString()).ColumnNames);
           rs = rs.FROM(data.ToString());
           rs = rs.Execute();
```

It gives me an error that it cannot find "COLUMNS".

While debugging, it seems that ***rs*** is picking up all the **return methods** and **private variables** in the SELECT class it just is not picking up the method like COLUMNS in the SELECT class at runtime. This is very odd, I expected it to also pick up the methods, I am doing something wrong???

**UPDATE**

The definition for **db** in   **db**.SELECT.COLUMNS(db.GetTable(data.ToString()).ColumnNames); is

```
 public class Database
{
    private Dictionary<string, ITable> _tables = new Dictionary<string, ITable>();

    public ITable AddTable(string tableName, string[]columnNames, Type[] columnTypes)
    {
        ITable tbl = new Table(tableName);
        tbl.SetColumns(columnNames, columnTypes);
        _tables.Add(tableName.ToUpper(), tbl);

        return tbl;
    }

    public ITable GetTable(string tableName)
    {
        return _tables[tableName.ToUpper()];
    }

    public ISELECT SELECT
    {
        get
        {
            ISELECT select = new SELECT(this);
            return select;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string,ITable> getTables()
    {
        return _tables;
    }
}
```

The definition for **SELECT** in   db.**SELECT**.COLUMNS(db.GetTable(data.ToString()).ColumnNames); which is an interface to my **SELECT** class;

```
public interface ISELECT
{
    ISELECT TOP(Int32 N);
    ISELECT DISTINCT { get; }
    ISELECTCOLUMN COLUMN(string columnName);
    ISELECTTABLECOLUMN COLUMN(string tableName, string columnName);
    ISELECTCOLUMNS COLUMNS(params string[] columnNames);
    ISELECTSUMCOLUMN SUM(string columnName);
    ISELECTSUMCOLUMN SUM(string tableName, string columnName);
}
```

This is where the problem lies, the dynamic object is not picking up the methods in the interface, it picks up all private variables and the only method it picks up is **"DISTINCT"**.

Below is part of the definition of the SELECT class, there is alot of code in it so I will just put a little;

```
internal class SELECT : ISELECT, ISELECTInternals
{
    private Database _dw;
    private bool _DISTINCT;
    private Int32 _TOPN = -1;
    private List<Int32> _JOINNumbers = new List<Int32>();
    private string[] _selectJOINLHScolumnTableNames;
    private string[] _selectJOINLHScolumnNames;
    private string[] _selectJOINRHScolumnTableNames;
    private string[] _selectJOINRHScolumnNames;
    private string[] _selectcolumnTableNames;
    private string[] _selectcolumnNames;
    private string[] _selectcolumnAliases;
    private object[] _selectcolumnLiterals;
    private string[] _selectcolumnStringTemplates;
    private AggregateTypes[] _selectcolumnAggregates;
    private string[] _queryTableNames;
    private string _SUMcolumnName;
    private string _FROMTableName;
    private List<string> _INNERJOINTableNames = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _JOINTableNames = new List<string>();
    private List<JoinTypes> _TableJoinTypes = new List<JoinTypes>();
    private bool _takeANDFlag = true;
    private List<string> _filterColumnTableNames = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _filterColumnNames = new List<string>();
    private List<object[]> _filterColumnValues = new List<object[]>();
    private List<string> _GROUPBYcolumnTableNames = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _GROUPBYcolumnNames = new List<string>();
```

etc.

Comment: It's hard to help when we know nothing about the implementation. Could you give more information, or ideally a short but complete example? Are you using explicit interface implementation anywhere?

Comment: @Jon I have edited my post, if you need any more information let me know, do not want to paste alot of code, might become unreadable.

Comment: Need more detail on what is failing. What does you ISELECTCOLUMNS interface define?

Comment: Are you sure you want dynamic not var? If you use dynamic youll have to cast in order to access the methods as by definition the compiler has no idea what the methods are until runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else has to have changed. Altering where or if a particular expression is captured does not cause it to throw an exception before it stores the value/reference.

Perhaps using statements or other types have changed and you didn't realize that between the success of the line

```
IResultSEt rs =    db.SELECT.COLUMNS(db.GetTable(data.ToString()).ColumnNames)
```

and the failure of the line

```
dynamic rs = db.SELECT.COLUMNS(db.GetTable(data.ToString()).ColumnNames);
```

but it failing on locating a method on db means that either the type of db has changed or the usings that would import extension methods have changed.

Let me try to restate.  The left side of the storage has NO effect on how the right side is evaluated until the entire right side is done evaluating. (not accounting for the left side saying `Expression<Func<>>` vs. `Func<>`)

I think more has changed since you put the question together that wasn't accounted for in the question or the source code posted in the question.